# Problem with Java while trying to run pycharm-community-4.5

Tags: 14.04, python, java, 64-bit, jdk

I've just installed pycharm-community-4.5 into my Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit). After installing I ran the command `/opt/pycharm-community-4.5/bin$ ./pycharm.sh` to run pycharm but the terminal showed me some errors as following-

```
Unrecognized VM option MaxPermSize=350m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Here is the result of my `java -version` :

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Java, the root of all evil.

Comment: :( nothing to do.

Comment: MaxPermSize support was removed in Java 8.0. But I can't find the entry. The entry in `pycharm.vmoptions` does not seem to be working. I have downloaded the latest PyCharm version and it works in Ubuntu 15.04. without a change.

Comment: Do you have a java in the PyCharm installation? The error message does not look like Oracle Java or OpenJDK.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `echo "$PYCHARM_JDK"`

Comment: And check if you have a folder `/opt/pycharm-community-4.5/jre`

Answer (score 8):

Open the file `pycharm64.vmoptions`

```
nano /opt/pycharm-community-4.5/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions
```

and add a `#` at the beginning of the line

```
# -XX:MaxPermSize=350m
```

Open the file `pycharm.vmoptions`

```
nano /opt/pycharm-community-4.5/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
```

and add a `#` at the beginning of the line

```
# -XX:MaxPermSize=250m
```

---

MaxPermSize support was removed in Java 8.0, but the error message

```
Unrecognized VM option MaxPermSize=350m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

does not look like Oracle Java 8 or OpenJDK 8.

The PyCharm starter `pycharm.sh` tries to find Java:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
# Try (in order): PYCHARM_JDK, ../jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, "java" in PATH.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
if [ -n "$PYCHARM_JDK" -a -x "$PYCHARM_JDK/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$PYCHARM_JDK"
elif [ -x "$IDE_HOME/jre/bin/java" ] && "$IDE_HOME/jre/bin/java" -version > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  JDK="$IDE_HOME/jre"
elif [ -n "$JDK_HOME" -a -x "$JDK_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$JDK_HOME"
elif [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" -a -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$JAVA_HOME"
else
  JAVA_BIN_PATH=`which java`
  if [ -n "$JAVA_BIN_PATH" ]; then
    if [ "$OS_TYPE" = "FreeBSD" -o "$OS_TYPE" = "MidnightBSD" ]; then
      JAVA_LOCATION=`JAVAVM_DRYRUN=yes java | "$GREP" '^JAVA_HOME' | "$CUT" -c11-`
      if [ -x "$JAVA_LOCATION/bin/java" ]; then
        JDK="$JAVA_LOCATION"
      fi
    elif [ "$OS_TYPE" = "SunOS" ]; then
      JAVA_LOCATION="/usr/jdk/latest"
      if [ -x "$JAVA_LOCATION/bin/java" ]; then
        JDK="$JAVA_LOCATION"
      fi
    elif [ "$OS_TYPE" = "Darwin" ]; then
      JAVA_LOCATION=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
      if [ -x "$JAVA_LOCATION/bin/java" ]; then
        JDK="$JAVA_LOCATION"
      fi
    fi

    if [ -z "$JDK" -a -x "$READLINK" -a -x "$XARGS" -a -x "$DIRNAME" ]; then
      JAVA_LOCATION=`"$READLINK" -f "$JAVA_BIN_PATH"`
      case "$JAVA_LOCATION" in
        */jre/bin/java)
          JAVA_LOCATION=`echo "$JAVA_LOCATION" | "$XARGS" "$DIRNAME" | "$XARGS" "$DIRNAME" | "$XARGS" "$DIRNAME"`
          if [ ! -d "$JAVA_LOCATION/bin" ]; then
            JAVA_LOCATION="$JAVA_LOCATION/jre"
          fi
          ;;
        *)
          JAVA_LOCATION=`echo "$JAVA_LOCATION" | "$XARGS" "$DIRNAME" | "$XARGS" "$DIRNAME"`
          ;;
      esac
      if [ -x "$JAVA_LOCATION/bin/java" ]; then
        JDK="$JAVA_LOCATION"
      fi
    fi
  fi
fi
```

1. `$PYCHARM_JDK`
2. `$IDE_HOME/jre/bin/java`
3. `$JDK_HOME`
4. `$JAVA_HOME`

Make sure you are using the Java version that you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

Look inside the `bin` folder of the pycharm folder you extracted.

There are files called `pycharm64.vmoptions` and `pycharm.vmoptions`. Inside them, you can delete the line with the culprit option of `MaxPermSize=350m`.