# pycharm 4.5 freezes the moment the autocompletion popup appears

Tags: upgrade, freeze, pycharm, 15.10

just today after an upgrade to ubuntu 15.10 I seem to be **unable to use** the pycharm 4.5.4 (from getdeb).

typing away launches the autocompletion suggestion pop-up and then pycharm just freezes, even **blocking/ignoring window close events** on its window.

xkill does the trick.

...searching for an answer, found [something similar](https://askubuntu.com/q/624199/381348)

Comment: pycharm about shows java version openjdk 1.8...

Answer (score 0):

**found solution**

enforcing other java version does the trick.

- just as mentioned in above question's [link](https://askubuntu.com/q/624199/381348), set environment variable in

  > ~/.bashrc
- by appending the line

  > export PYCHARM_JDK='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64'
- and make sure you also have the openjdk java 7 installed.
- logout of unity, log in again
- starting pycharm should show an about message referring to openjre 1.7.* as java version

Answer (score 0):

**the other answers failed for me, so this is how i did it**:

downgrade jdk 1.8 to 1.7 - by removing openjdk, pycharm is removed as well. then i reinstalled openjdk-7, followed by pycharm. now i can autocomlete without stuff freezing upon showing autocompletion window.

$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk-*

$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm

$ sudo apt-get install pycharm-community