# Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit. Problems with PyCharm Community

Tags: python, java, 32-bit, pycharm

I've got a same problem as a guy [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624199/problem-with-java-while-trying-to-run-pycharm-community-4-5). But I have 32 bit system.

I've tried to fix it as the top answer advices, but instead of working pycharm I catch much more problems, which are wroten at [this log file](http://pastebin.com/7VgxWikF).

//There's no solution for me at his post, so I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you have the same issue as someone else then don't post a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with Java while trying to run pycharm-community-4.5](http://askubuntu.com/questions/624199/problem-with-java-while-trying-to-run-pycharm-community-4-5)

Comment: But there's no solution at his post.

Comment: There are two answers posted and I doubt they tested or they would have replied - do either of those answers help you?

Comment: They are same, if you'll look again.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question about whether it worked or not and not answering that question doesn't help

Comment: I quote myself: "I've tried to fix it as the top answer advices, but instead of working pycharm I catch much more problems, which are wroten at this log file."

Comment: Then it is safe to assume there is no resolution and you should still not post duplicates.

Comment: @ThomasW. If you can't get other answers to work it is perfectly fine to ask a new question provided you disclose that they are the same question and the previous answers don't work, which the OP did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem (probably bug?) in the OpenJDK Java 9 Runtime Environment which is used by PyCharm.

Java 9 is still in its development phase and can't be expected to be stable until around March 2017.

You should remove Java 9 and install and use Java 8 instead.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt purge openjdk-9-*
```

But before you confirm the second command (purge Java 9), please check the shown list of packages that will be removed. If anything you installed depends directly on Java 9, it will get removed as well. Cancel and report back if something is listed there that you want to keep or are unsure about.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey check button on its left. Otherwise feel free to comment and ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much, it doesn't work your way, but I've just installed jdk8 from oracle site instead of openjdk9 and it works properly!